# How can I determine the available icon sizes contained in an icon resource?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, icons, dpi-aware

I'm going through the painful process of making my MFC application DPI aware. I'm planning to include [icon resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381018(v=vs.85).aspx) that contain different icon sizes. For example, small icons for [list view controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx) should get the sizes: 16x16, 20x20, 24x24, etc. [as recommend by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742485(v=vs.85).aspx).

I know I can use [`LoadImage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045(v=vs.85).aspx) (or even [`LoadIconWithScaleDown()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775703(v=vs.85).aspx)) to load an icon of the needed size as follows:

```
HICON hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance,
                               MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYICON),
                               IMAGE_ICON,
                               GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),
                               GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON),
                               LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
```

As explained in the Remarks section of the documentation on [`LoadIconWithScaleDown()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775703(v=vs.85).aspx), if an icon size is not available, `LoadImage()` scales a smaller icon up and `LoadIconWithScaleDown()` scales a larger icon down. However, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24229982/2675154) by David Heffernan, I should try to avoid scaling icons (at least small ones):

> [...] For instance, if system metrics suggest an 18px icons, and you only have 16px and 20px icons, then make a new 18px icons.
>   Fill the image with transparent pixels, and blit the 16px icon into the middle of this 18px image. Make the icon out of that. [...]

I'd like to do so, but for reasons of robustness, I don't want to make any assumptions on the available icon sizes.
Therefore, I want to determine the available icon sizes of an icon resource dynamically at runtime.
However, none of the [icon functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468847(v=vs.85).aspx) that I found seem to provide such kind of functionality.

How can I find out, which icon sizes are available in my icon resource (e.g. `IDI_MYICON`)?

Comment: This might help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120720-00/?p=7083

Comment: There is also [`LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648074(v=vs.85).aspx) which could simplify the code. By using this function one could get rid of `GetIconDirectory()` in the linked answer. No need to manually enumerate `GRPICONDIR` structures.

Comment: @zett42: If that function always returns the next smaller icon (in case there is no match), then it would indeed help. I wish I would have just 10% of your knowledge ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: The reference does not explicitly say that it returns the next smaller icon but it mentions that this function is used by `LoadImage()` which does so.

Comment: @zett42: This is exactly what I concluded as well :)